# MAMP MySQL Server wont start

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mamp

Apologies if this is a repeat, I have had a look at the other questions and cant find a solution. I'm not really very knowledgable about this stuff so apologies if im asking dumb questions...

With my MAMP install when I try and start it up, Apache starts fine, but MySQL doesn't. I fixed this problem before by uninstalling it and reinstalling it, however I cant uninstall MAMP again as I have a website already built in Wordpress in it and don't want to loose the database...

Here is the MySQL Log, i'm not really sure what any of this means:

https://codeshare.io/GqPykx

Any help would be greatly appreciated

K

Comment: Or failing fixing MAMP how do I rescue my MySQL database?

Comment: for second question (in the comment above), you should spawn another thread for better chance at getting answer...

Comment: ok thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

OK, managed to get it to start.

in APPLICATIONS > MAMP > db > mysql56 > (Delete all files other than the folders).

MySQL starts after this, but table appears to be corrupted......sigh

Comment: I would say that you deleted some files that are involved with either directly storing your database or, at least, metadata about the database itself. Either way, I suspect that the trouble with the corrupted tables might be related to this. I'd try restoring the files and then working through any error messages MySQL presents. The last few lines of the error log (743-757) are pretty clear about possible steps for recovery from that situation. I would start by checking that the file `olivia/wp_term_taxonomy.ibd` exists (within the MySQL data directory) and compare permissions to other files.